# etc2 textures not working on OpenGL ES 3.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

For a side Android project I need to use compressed textures with alpha blending. etc2 seems like a good choice and should be supported on OpenGL ES 3+, but I cannot get them to work. I feel like I am missing something trivial.

While etc1 textures work great (but lack alpha), etc2 textures fail both on my device (Mi A1, Android 9) and on the emulator. When creating the texture, GLES30.glCompressedTexImage2D results in error 1281 (Invalid Value).

```
    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        val vers = IntArray(2)
        GLES30.glGetIntegerv(GLES30.GL_MAJOR_VERSION, vers, 0)
        GLES30.glGetIntegerv(GLES30.GL_MINOR_VERSION, vers, 1)
        LOG.info("GLES version: ${vers[0]}.${vers[1]}")

        if (vers[0] > 3 || vers[0] == 3 && vers[1] >= 1) {
            // We have at least ES 3.1.
        }
        // first, try to generate a texture handle
        GLES30.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)

        if (textures[0] == GLES30.GL_FALSE)
            throw RuntimeException("Error loading texture")

        // bind the texture and set parameters
        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST)
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST)

        val resId = R.raw.texture_etc2
        //val resId = R.raw.texture_etc1

        val texture = ETC2Util.createTexture(context.resources.openRawResource(resId))
        LOG.info("compressionFormat: " + texture.compressionFormat + ", capacity: " + texture.data.capacity())
        GLES30.glCompressedTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture.compressionFormat, texture.width, texture.height, 0,
            texture.data.capacity(), texture.data);
        LOG.info("error: " + GLES30.glGetError())
    }
```

Although the GLES version is high enough, glGetError returns error 1281:

```
I/TextureRenderer: GLES version: 3.2
D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
I/ETC2Util: width: 128, height: 128, format: 37496, encoded size: 8192
I/TextureRenderer: compressionFormat: 37496, capacity: 8192
    error: 1281
```

Note that 37496 is equal to GLES30.GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC.

When I use the etc1 texture, everything runs smoothly. glGetError returns 0 and the texture can be used normally (except for the 'no alpha' part of course).
When I use the etc2 texture glGetError returns 1281 and the texture remains black.

The problem does not appear to be in the actual texture data but purely in the internalFormat parameter: if I specify the etc1 texture format (36196, 0x8D64, strangely not found in GLES30?) but use the etc2 data no error is reported but garbage is shown on the screen because OpenGL ES tries to interpret etc2 data as etc1.

It feels like etc2 is just not supported but all sources I find claim etc2 support is mandatory on OpenGL ES 3.0 and higher on Android?

Comment: `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC` is 1 byte per pixel so a 128x128 texture of that format should be 16384 bytes not 8192. Maybe the format is actually `GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2` or `GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2`, or perhaps `capacity()` isn't returning bytes, or perhaps there are issues with `ETC2Util` or whatever tool generated your etc2 texture.

Comment: Learn to use the `glDebugMessage*()` functions (previously part of the `KHR_debug` extension, but they are core in 3.2); you'll usually get much more sensible error messages not just the error code.

Comment: The ETC2Util class indeed calculated the size incorrectly for RGBA8_ETC2_EAC and read in too few bytes from the .pkm file containing the texture. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I will re-attempt to use the glDebugMessage*() functions. My initial attempt stranded because calling GLES32.glDebugMessageCallback  crashed with a 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not yet implemented'. Dismissing the other glDebugMessage* methods because of this might have been premature.

Comment: Ah, from Java you are probably right unfortunately. It's useful enough you might want to punch though a small native code module to do it though ...

Comment: I’m having the same issue so I reverted back to OpenGL ES 2.0 for now.